# Returning False to getFormattedMessage for LoggingEvent

Tags: mockito, appender

I am using the mockAppender method of the Appender class and I am trying to figure how to have the following snippet of code return true if either the text below is not logged, or `.doAppend` is not called at all.

```
verify(mockAppender).doAppend(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher() {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(final Object argument) {
    return ((LoggingEvent) argument).getFormattedMessage().contains(
        "Sending request to partner: "
        + "https://<URL>/hosted/api/tokenize with args");
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I figured out another way as well. Using an additional parameter on the verify method:

```
verify(mockAppender, never()).doAppend(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher() {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(final Object argument) {
    return ((LoggingEvent) argument).getFormattedMessage().contains(
        "Sending request to partner: "
        + "https://<URL>/hosted/api/tokenize with args");
  }
}));
```

Comment: When you found the other answer helpful, then *accept* to show that!

Comment: Actually that will not work.  That will only verify that the method is never called with an argument meeting the matcher condition.  The verify would "work" even if `doAppend` were never called at all.  The way I showed in my answer verifies both that the method is called and it was called with a parameter that does not meet the matcher condition.  And it avoids the complexity of having to define an anonymous inner class.

Comment: I think I worded my original question wrong.  I have clarified it to make it more clear.

Comment: I don't think your code will work Kevin.  What is the variable logEventCaptor?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, simply return the inverse:

```
return !((LogginEvent) ... etc.
```

Just as a suggestion, you might consider using an @Captor in your verify instead, and then asserting on the @Captor's value:

```
ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoggingEvent.class);
// or more succinct to use a field with @Captor annotation

verify(mockAppender).doAppend(logEventCaptor);
assertFalse(logEventCaptor.getValue().contains("theTextYouWantToExclude");
```